# Gradle Findbugs Plugin

Tags: java, gradle, findbugs

I am trying to run findbugs on my Gradle project to analyze it. Since my project is rather big and has a lot of subprojects i have put all the compiled jar and third party files into a separate folder.

```
apply plugin: 'findbugs'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

task customFindbugs(type: FindBugs) {
    ignoreFailures = false
    effort = "max"
    reportLevel = "low"
    classes = files("output/libs/jar")
    classpath = files("output/3pps/jar")

    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        xml.withMessages = true
        html.enabled = true
        xml.destination "$project.buildDir/output/findbugs/findbugs-output.xml"
        html.destination "$project.buildDir/output/findbugs/findbugs-output.html"
    }
}
```

This is the code i use. Here i define a new task which should analyze jars from the "output/libs/jar" and set classpath to "output/3pps/jar" .

It worked for the command line findbugs to analyze these files , however when i try to execute the task, literally nothing happens...

Gradle just tells me that everything is up-to-date but no files have been analyzed, nor any output has been generated...

Comment: Try setting `uptodatewhen` on your task.  [google search](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=gradle+uptodatewhen&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Comment: Try using `fileTree` instead of `files` for `classes` and `classpath`. Tell me if that solved it, then I make this an answer.

Comment: @dsh that will not help if the task has no inputs to work on. It will not be displayed as up-to-date, but nevertheless be useless. ;-)

Comment: Thank you guys, for your answers. the `fileTree` fix didnt work ...
Adding `outputs.upToDateWhen{false}` also didnt help :(

Comment: Are you sure your path to the classes and classpath is correct, relative to the project dir? Remove the upToDateWhen which is non-sense in this case and is even counterproductive once you get your task configured properly as it voids the up-to-date checks which is one of the big strengths of Gradle. Then re-run Gradle with -i and it should tell you why it skipps the task. If e. g. it says "no input files" then your classes are not setup correctly, but are empty. If this is the case, try adding `files("output/libs/jar").each { println it.absolutePath + " / " + it.exists }` to verify your setup.

Comment: Thank you @Vampire , the problem was that i did not have source files defined. Adding `source = fileTree("out/3pp/jar")` helped.